# Default string to calculate size of

Tags: c#, user-interface, fonts, unity-game-engine

In my GUI code, I have a input text string that changes it's size according with the string and style it has. I have an existing string, it works perfect. However, I need to provide some default height for the case when the string is empty. Right now in this case I just use "X" to calculate it.

Is it correct? May be there's more uniform way to calculate it? I want this to work for any font, and my project also has to support a LOT of languages.

Comment: What sort of application is this? WinForms, WPF...?

Comment: We have custom GUI framework based on Unity3d, but I don't think that this question is specific to some GUI framework.

Comment: You can't just use `Font.Height`?

Answer (score 0):

`.Net` class `Font` has `Height` and `SizeInPoints` properties, may be you can get benefit of [them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.font.height.aspx)

Comment: I'm not using this class, and I'm trying to treat CalcSize(string) method that I use as a black box.

Comment: so the height returned by `CalcSize(string)` doesn't depend on font?

Comment: It depends on various things, including style settings, contents of the string, whether we support rendering emoji's that are present in the string, etc.

Comment: then your approach seems fine. Just check in `CalcSize(string)` if `String.IsNullOrEmpty(string)` for example and perform needed computations. It's hard to advise something without looking into the code.